# Creating Promises in Parallel

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Just trying my hands with **es6 and promises**.

**Is there any way to use promises to perform several tasks in parallel ?**

I want to start multiple operations at once, and use Promise to create a new promise that will be resolved when all of its input promises is resolved.

The **new promise** will be **successful** if none of the **passed-in promises fail**; otherwise, it will fail with the last error.

All I know about promises is - how to create promises and chain them.

```
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do a thing, possibly async, then…

  if (/* everything turned out fine */) {
    resolve("Successfully completed!");
  }
  else {
    reject(Error("Error occurred!"));
  }
});

promise.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result); // "Successfully completed!"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err); // Error: "Error occurred!"
});
```

Comment: javascript does not have multithreading.

Comment: Have a look at `Promise.all` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799269/queuing-promises

Comment: @MarcoL yes exactly thats what I needed. But I wish you could write an answer Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are looking for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise/all)

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve(1)
const p2 = Promise.resolve(2)
const p3 = Promise.resolve(3)

const p4 = Promise.all([p1, p2, p3])

p4.then(values => console.log(values)) // [1, 2, 3]
```