# Promise 2 resolves before the Promise 1

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise, rxjs

I am doing a search in the textfield and as I type, there is a call going to the backend after say 100ms.

For example, if we search "5041" and immediately search for "50" and again make it "5041", then there are 3 calls made to the backend.

```
1."5041" -> Promise 1

2."50"   -> Promise 2

3."5041" -> Promise 3
```

However, promise 3 (web call takes 200ms) resolves before promise 2 (web call takes 500ms) which makes the screen reflect results for promise 2 ("50") when all I have in the textfield is "5041".

I need some way to let user type in the textfield without blocking the user along with the ability to show results for only the last call.

**This is something that can be achieved using `switchMap` from rxjs in an angular app. However I need a way to achieve the same in vanilla JS.**

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: you should show a progress bar , loader in each search and do not allow the user to search for other values before the first search results succeeds, or wait for first promise to resolve , after resolving that only u should trigger the second search and so on

Comment: This is how promises and asynchronous code works. There isn't a well defined order. You can create your own mechanism to avoid this. For example you could attach a counter to each request and if `currentIndex > promiseIndex`, then you will discard it. (`currentIndex` will be incremented each time a new request will be made).

Comment: Nature of promises is they can resolve in any order. You can instead wait until first promise resolves, then initiate second promise, and when that resolves finally make the 3rd promise? But what is the logic you need to achieve? You can do `Promise.all(p1,p2,p3).then` and just use p3 result.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV we are showing loader but issue is we are debouncing if user type continuously otherwise there will floods of calls.

Comment: @AdrianPop LEt me try this.

Comment: @JGFMK thanks for sharing. Anyway I have already seen this video.

Comment: So are you calling this method in keyup or keydown events ? or in button click ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV on keyup

Comment: ok then one option is to use a counter variable it should increase in each of your keyup events , so just equate the counter with response and show only the last item , drawback : U miss all the other results.

Comment: Or you can go with promise queues

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV can you please share any link regarding promise queue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21799269/queuing-promises this is one link related to promise queue

Comment: What does this have to do with angular if you're only allowed to use vanilla?

Answer (score 4):

First you can wrap your `fetchData` function into a something like `fetchLatestSearchResults` function **which notes the time when network call was made** and **return the latest result from all the network calls**(irrespective of what data was returned from server)

```js
const generateLatestSearchFetch = function(fetchFunc){
  let mostRecentResult = null;
  let mostRecentResultFetchTime = Date.now();

  return (...args) => {

    const myFetchStartTime = Date.now();

    return fetchFunc(...args)
      .then(data => {
        if (myFetchStartTime > mostRecentResultFetchTime) {
          mostRecentResult = data;
          mostRecentResultFetchTime = myFetchStartTime
        }
        return mostRecentResult;  
      });
  }
};
```

**Use Like**:

```
fetchData = generateLatestSearchFetch(fetchData);
fetchData('10'); // resolves first and returns result for 10
fetchData('102'); // resolves third and returns result for 1024
fetchData('1024'); // resolves second and returns result for 1024
```

**Last** but not the least, use `debounce` [more on this](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) to optimize number of network calls made for every type event.

Answer (score 3):

You need a "last" function:

```
// takes a function returning a promise and only reports the last resort
function last(fn) { 
  let p;
  return function(...args) {
    let current = fn(); // call the function
    p = current; // mark it as the last call
    return p.then(result => { 
      // ask am I still the last call?
      if (p === current) return result;
      else return new Promise(() => {}); // never resolve
    });
  }
}

let onlyLastSearch = last((name) => fetch('/api?name=' + name));

onlyLastSearch('a'); // will be ignored
onlyLastSearch('b'); // will be ignored
onlyLastSearch('c'); // only relevant result
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use observer pattern for this.

```
const createWrapper = (fn) => {
    let counter = 0;
    let lastFetchId = 0;
    const listeners = [];
    return {
        fetch: (str) => {
            let id = ++counter;
            fn(str).then((data) => {
                if(id > lastFetchId) {
                    listeners.forEach(fn => {
                        fn(data);
                    });
                    lastFetchId = id;
                }
            });
        },
        listen: (fn) => {
            listeners.push(fn);
            return () => {
                const index = listeners.indexOf(fn);
                listeners.splice(index, 1);
            };
        }
    }
}

const SearchWrapper = createWrapper(fetchData);

SearchWrapper.fetch('a');
SearchWrapper.fetch('b');
SearchWrapper.fetch('c');

SearchWrapper.listen((data) => {
    console.log(data);
})
```